# sap.m.Input: How to bind valueState

Tags: sapui5

I want this result: [image]

I have a state JSONModel contains the states that I want bind with my UI.

```json
{
  code:"None",
  descr:"Error"
  family:"None"
}
```

Now, to have my result, I write:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().byId("idCodeInput").setValueState("{state>code}");
sap.ui.getCore().byId("idDescrInput").setValueState("{state>descr}");
sap.ui.getCore().byId("idFamilyInput").setValueState("{state>family}");
```

and it works fine.

But `sap.m.Input` doesn't not have `valueState` property and I can't bind model<-->view from the XML of view. I would like write some like this:

```xml
<Input 
  valueState ="{state>descr}"
  value="{model>descr}"
  enabled="{enable>descr}"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sap.m.Input` has a property `valueState`

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Input.html